# How to remove the changes of git in visual studio code?

Tags: git, visual-studio, github

[image]

Each time I open the visual studio code, it will load tons of changes that is unfamiliar to me. I want to disable or remove the changes that I circled in the left panel of the above screenshot.

I am new to git and github. I have search many solution but none of them are work. Is their any method to remove the unwanted changes at the left panel of the visual studio code?

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit (or create) your .gitignore file, located at the same level as your .git folder. Once commited, files/folders listed will not be included in stageable changesfor next commits.

Note that wildcards are allowed (example : *.pdf will ignore all pdf files)

Mainly, you have to point folders where build produce files.

[.gitignore manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)
[Usefull .gitignore templates](https://github.com/github/gitignore)

Answer (score -1):

open the prompt from the project folder and type:
git merge